# Auto increment property not key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to auto increment a property which is not the primary key in Entity Framework? What I have is a class which has an ID, but also a serial number:

```
public class Maintenance
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; } 
}
```

I have an index on `GroupID` and `SerialNo` with a unique relation, making it impossible for a group to have the same serial number twice.

What I'm currently doing is checking `.Max()` for `SerialNo` within that group. I would however like it if the serial number got auto incremented. Is this possible?

I have been searching for a solution, but as far as I understand it, it's not possible to have 2 auto incrementing columns with entity framework, and that the auto incrementing column will always be the PK column.

Is there a way to set auto increment, or is there a better solution to the problem than using `Max()`? Using `Max()` may theoretically produce 2 values that are identical and will result in crashing the program while trying to insert (because of the unique index).

I'm using code first.

To clarify: I want to keep the ID as primary key, and compute the serial number while inserting.

UPDATE:

I've tried using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on `SerialNo` which results in entity framework wanting to change the primary key to this property. I also tried `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`, which tries to insert NULL into the `SerialNo`column, and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` which tries to insert 0, basically doing 'nothing'.

REQUESTED INFO:

This is an example of how the table could look:

```
|_ID_|_GroupID_|_SerialNo_|
|  1 |    1    |    1     |
|  2 |    1    |    2     |
|  3 |    2    |    1     |
|  4 |    1    |    3     |
|  5 |    2    |    2     |
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same question/issue...

Comment: No, sorry @Mike I didn't. I'm still using `.Max()`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the [following attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int SerialNo { get; set; }
```

See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) for a list of possible data annotations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. It will be very helpful. Using `DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity` will force `SerialNo` to become the primary key for the object, which is not what I want. I want to keep the ID as primary key, and compute the serial number while inserting.

Comment: @RobinDorbell: `I want to keep the ID as primary key, and compute the serial number while inserting.` - that makes absolutely sense, but is not what you asked for ;-). Maybe you can give us some examples how your rows should/can look like?

Comment: It's `DatabaseGeneratedOption` and not `DatabaseGenerationOption`.

Comment: @JoSmo: thanks for the catch - it is actually also wrong on the official EF-page I linked to -> I'll send them a note...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using EF Core you should use the Sequence for the solution.

```
    public class Project
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

And than you configure your onModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("ProjectId").StartsAt(100).IncrementsBy(1);
modelBuilder.Entity< Project>().Property(o => o.ProjectId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR ProjectId");
```

or you can read more on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server than also read this carefully

[Can we have more than one identity columns in a table.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic945215-391-1.aspx)

---

So i think below code compile but will give you an error when trying to migrate / create database.

you can also use fluent api approch like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Maintenance>().Property(a => a.GroupID 
                          ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Maintenance>().Property(a => a.SerialNo 
                          ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```